# Read every line out of a txt

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader, filereader

Hey there im trying to read a .txt file line by line but somehow it only reads every second line..

```
try {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("file.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    while (br.readLine() != null){
        println(br.readLine());     //method to print the line
    }
}catch (FileNotFoundException e){}
```

This is what it should print:

```
stuff
stuff
stuff
more stuff
SAVED
LOADED
SAVED
LOADED
```

Instead it just prints this:

```
stuff
more stuff
LOADED
LOADED
```

I have no idea whats going on and could really use some help

Comment: Because you are calling `readLine()` twice, once in the loop check and once in the `println()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-using-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling `br.readLine()` you are **already** reading but your first call is just to make sure you have a return value which ist not null. Go with something like this:

```
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   println(line);
}
```